# Issue understanding sums of subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am having a bit of trouble with an example for sums of subspaces. It states

Suppose $U=\{(x,x,y,y)∈F^4:x,y∈F\}$ and $W=\{(x,x,x,y)∈F^4:x,y∈F\}$ Then goes on to say that $U+W=\{(x,x,y,z)∈F^4:x,y,z∈F\}$

I'm a bit confused because in my mind it should be $U+W=\{(x,x,z,y)∈F^4:x,y,z∈F\}$ (note the $y$ and $z$ switched around) as $u_3+w_3=x+y=z$ (I believe $z$ is just an arbitrary variable but I may be wrong). Am I wrong in my thinking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are definitely right, as $U+W$ is spanned by elements of the form:
$$(x,x,y,y)+(x',x',y',z')=(x+x',x+x',y+y',y+z')=(x'',x'',y'',z'').$$

Comment: Now I feel more confused... So $U+W=\{(x,x,y,z)\in\mathbb{F}^4:x,y,z\in\mathbb{F}\}?$ (Apologies I haven't learnt what span really is yet).

Comment: What is your definition of $U+W$ then? The smallest subspace of $\mathbb{F}^4$ which contains $U$ and $W$?

Comment: Yes, although this example comes before that is stated under "sums of subspaces"

Comment: All you have to know is that each element of $U+W$ is given by a linear combination of elements of the form $u+w$, where $u\in U$ and $w\in W$.

Comment: Okay so in my example given, what exactly is $U+W$? Is it as you have given in the answer, $(x'', x'', y'', z'')$? I am only confused as you have said I am 'definitely right', whereas it being $(x'', x'', y'', z'')$ would make me wrong.

Comment: The name of the variables is irrelevant, I could have used $(x,x,y,z)$. Your answer is right.

Comment: Okay, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Your version of $U+W$ and the given one describe exactly the same set of vectors. The specific names given to the variables in the set’s description are irrelevant. The set could just as well have been described as $\{(a,a,b,c)\in F^4 : a,b,c\in F\}$. Perhaps what’s confusing you is that you’re trying to identify the $x$, $y$, $z$ in the specification of $U+W$ with the ones in the specifications of $U$ and $W$; they are different variables in each case.

Comment: Oh I see - It seems silly that I was even trying to justiy (x,x,z,y) then, really... Thanks :)